# boost, c++ and fatal error: boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost

Below is my list of includes.  When I run the program I get this error..

```
fatal error: boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Well...problem is the file is there and when I comment out the include the other files are found and the program compiles.  I really don't understands how this happens.  Any explanation?

My boost home is /home/ubuntu/boost/ so the path is /home/ubuntu/boost/boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp

Here is how I invoke:

```
 g++ rtb.cpp -o rtb.o -L/home/ubuntu/boost  -L/usr/local/include/ -lfcgi++
```

Here are te includes

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
```

Comment: Which version of boost in in  /home/ubuntu/boost/ and which in /usr/local/include ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using -L (which gives the directories where the libraries of object files can be found)  when you should use -I giving the directory where the compiler will look for include files

[gcc's documentation for library search](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) also from [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.htmlhttp://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) /usr/local/include is always included.

Thus from @nttstar's answer that the uniform_int_distribution.hpp header was added in boost 1.47 an before that there's only uniform_int.hpp.

I think the reason why you see the error just for this one header is that you are finding an older boost in /usr/local/include

Comment: Only weird thing is that he claims only this header was problematic. But this is the right answer.

Comment: I think g++ does tend to look in /usr/local/include by default http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: Thank you sooo much....yes...I got burned by installing  libboost-dev for the first time in ubuntu.  Before I would leave boost in a different dir.  Great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mark.

If you only has problem with uniform_int_distribution.hpp, you should check your boost version.

The uniform_int_distribution.hpp header was added in boost 1.47. Before that there's only uniform_int.hpp. You can review the 1.46 random library docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_random.html)

Comment: I suspect then that 1.47 is in  /home/ubuntu/boost/ and my fix fixes that and an older boost is in /usr/local/include